# How do you make a map that has arrays inside of it and access each index of that array?

Tags: list, groovy

Basically I have some code like this in the bottom. This creates a lot of lists but is it possible to put all of these lists in a map? Also, I access each index in my for loop so is it possible to access these indexes in a map with lists inside of it? I am just trying to achieve shorter code and possibly more efficient.

```
//Create our lists
def htmlList = []
def pixProductList = []
def pixLanguageList = []
def pixOffercodeList = []
def pixVIDList = []
def pixStartDateList = []
def pixEndDateList = []
def pixContactList = []
def pixPublisherList = []
def newPixelList = []

//Parse the file
String file = new File('grails-app/controllers/pixel/editor/tool/trackingPixels.xml').text
newPixelList = StringUtils.substringsBetween(file, "<pixelNew", "</pixelNew>")

//Access each element in newPixelList 
for(int i =0; i < newPixelList.size(); i++){
    String newPixel = newPixelList[i]
    htmlList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<html>", "</html>")
    pixProductList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<product>", "</product>")
    pixLanguageList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<lang>", "</lang>")
    pixOffercodeList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<offercode>", "</offercode>")
    pixVIDList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<vid>", "</vid>")
    pixStartDateList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<startDate>", "</startDate>")
    pixEndDateList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<endDate>", "</endDate>")
    pixContactList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<contact>", "</contact>")
    pixPublisherList[i] = StringUtils.substringBetween(newPixel, "<publisher>", "</publisher>")
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can actually use an XML slurper and use that instead of this string manipulation.

```
def htmlList = []
def pixProductList = []
def pixLanguageList = []
def pixOffercodeList = []
def pixVIDList = []
def pixStartDateList = []
def pixEndDateList = []
def pixContactList = []
def pixPublisherList = []
def newPixelList = []

File file = new File('grails-app/controllers/pixel/editor/tool/trackingPixels.xml')
def xmlFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
def records = xmlFile.pixelNew //Assuming pixelNew is the top level node

records.each {
    htmlList.add(it.html.text())
    pixProductList.add(it.product.text())
    ...
}
```

Then you could create a class to store this data and populate the data in the constructor

```
class WhateverYouWant {
  String html
  String product
  ...

  public WhateverYouWant(NodeChild record) {
      this.html = record.html.text()
      this.product = record.product.text()
      ...
  }
}
```

Then you could simply do:

```
List<WhateverYouWant> items = []

xmlFile = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
def records = xmlFile.pixelNew //Assuming pixelNew is the top level node

records.each {
    items.add(new WhateverYouWant(it))
}
```

Comment: Man you are quick. Cudos. Only before I started typing I did a refresh to see if there is already an answer submitted. And you answered exactly what I was thinking of. :-)

Comment: Thanks! It helped that I did almost the exact same thing in the project I'm currently working on.. So mostly copy/paste. Whats nice about this is you can just overload the constructor to support different file types with the same data.

Comment: When you user XML Slurper, don't you need to use parseText() instead of parse()? Since "file" is a String not a file?

Comment: My mistake. I edited to get clear picture of the answer. See the update now @EliDavila

Comment: Well my question now is, how do you access the items? Ive tried something like println items[0] and it tells me something about the element not saved.

Comment: @EliDavila The problem may be unrelated to the present question. You should be accepting the appropriate answer which helps you move forward in your implementation and/or ask another question related to the present issue.

Comment: I try to access "items" but it just tells me "pixel.editor.tool.WhateverYouWant : (unsaved)". Do you know why?

Comment: Never mind. Just found out I was not accessing items correctly. I was doing this items.each { println it } but I should be doing like items.each { println it.product }